# leaflet and chroma.js .domain arguments not working

Tags: javascript, leaflet

I am trying to incorporate chroma.js into my leaflet map so that i can toggle between quantiles, equal interval, and k-means, but the second and third argument for the domain function does not change anything

```
  var colorScale = chroma.scale('YlGnBu').domain(voterList, 3, 'quantiles');
```

Here is the full code for the function

```
  this.getRegionItemColor = function(item) {
      var regionData = Mapbook.getRegionData();
      var voterList = Mapbook.getColorScheme();

      var colorScale = chroma.scale('YlGnBu').domain(voterList, 3, 'quantiles');

        if (!_.isUndefined(item)) {

            var voters = item.voters,
            minVoters = regionData.min_voters,
            maxVoters = regionData.max_voters;

            var alpha = colorScale(voters);
            return alpha;
        }
        else {
            return 0;
        }
    }
```

Does anyone know why changing the number of buckets or classification method does not change anything?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Strange... I looked into it and I do think there is a problem with the library. Let's consider a very simple and documented example.
If you look at the documentation on github, here is what is written (https://github.com/gka/chroma.js/wiki/Color-Scales):

```
// Calling .domain() with no arguments will return the current domain.
chroma.scale(['white', 'red']).domain([0, 100], 4).domain() // [0, 25, 50, 75, 100]
```

When I do the same, however, this returns [0,100] (and not [0, 25, 50, 75, 100]); as you said, the second argument has not changed anything. You may want to flag that behavior as a bug on the plugin github page. Unless someone has a good explanation?

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same problem, then I realized that at the time I defined 'ColorScale', my domain was not yet populated. are you certain that 'voterList' had your dataset in it at the time you defined ColorScale?